# json multiple selector in php

Tags: php, json

i have this output of json :

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "vm": "vm-1060",
            "name": "node10",
            "cpu_count": 16
        },
        {
            "vm": "vm-1063",
            "name": "node2",
            "cpu_count": 16
        },
        {
            "vm": "vm-1064",
            "name": "node0",
            "cpu_count": 16
        }
    ]
```

and i want to list (or select) all available value's named "vm" automatically , not manual selecting ! because my json outputs are variable

Comment: can be done various ways with [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_reduce](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) or a simple foreach, make an attempt then ask for help when you have issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use next simple code:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$values = array_column($arr['value'], 'vm');
```

[PHP array_column json_decode](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/81fab2785d2ea988ab69bf6f54560de9/)